# What happens to grails project on start if database is not running?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, grails, grails-orm

I have a grails project with mysql for GORM support. When i start project without mysql running, it gives me series of exception message. This is fine and expected. But, what is problem is that there is no way to handle that so that i can catch them and report to user that there is issue with system and they need to wait till it gets fixed.

There are two cases for this problem.

First one is when a currently running project (deployed inside tomcat and running) get its mysql connection killed by say stopping mysql service. In this case, it keeps on throwing database exception without any grace. The error catching mechanism fails for me. I have mapped 500 to a error page but it also does not gets rendered. Nginx which acts as reverse proxy at last displays its own timeout page.

Second case is when project start loading (say tomcat container is started) and mysql service is already down. In this case, the project startup seems to be effected to a level that startup fails though tomcat reports in log that war is running but when accessed it just throws black page (saying 404) which still is mysterious because i have mapped 404 to a error page which is also not in work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no db at start up the war will not be loaded into tomcat at all. So you will get default 404 error pages at that point. There are errors thrown to the log in this case but not much else. So your users are hosting their own instances of their app it sounds like, what I like to do is expose a health page.

The health page can be at a known URL and in the case of no db you will get a 404 but you can document that any non 200 status code is an error and provide info on how to fix. Also if you are automating deployment this check is great for reporting status of the deployment.

Comment: But, cant we somehow specify a backup database maybe h2 incase the mysql is not connected so that system would start atleast. Then in the code i can check for the source myself and do the necessary reporting and management. For me the database is not an important entity for system to run. But, i have added them in datasource file just to make reading things easier when required.

Comment: Setting up a datasource causes GORM to act a certain way. You are using hibernate with GORM so it needs to set up all of that before booting the app, if you want to fail over from MySQL to H2 that is something you will have to setup for hibernate. GORM just wants a datasource setup if you are using a plugin that requires it.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how can i specify this fail over from mysql to h2 in the datasource config file?

Comment: No it may not be exposed via that kind of config I'm not sure you will need to get lower into hibernate for this case